# How many divisors of $\phi(m)$ do not divide $m-1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

[Lehmer's totient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem) asks if there exists a composite number $m$ such that $\phi(m)$ divides $m-1$. Lower bounds on $m$ has been established but we do not know if a solution exists. Clearly, if we find a divisor of $\phi(m)$ which does not divide $m-1$ then $m$ cannot be a solution of the problem. I started counting the number of divisors of $\phi(m)$ which do not divide. Soon I noticed pattern:

- Composites of the form $m = 8k+3$ has at least $4$ divisors of $\phi(m)$ which do not divide $m-1$
- Composites of the form $m = 6k+5$ has at least $5$ divisors of $\phi(m)$ which do not divide $m-1$
- Composites of the form $m = 12k+7$ has at least $6$ divisors of $\phi(m)$ which do not divide $m-1$
- Composites of the form $m = 20k+3$ has at least $7$ divisors of $\phi(m)$ which do not divide $m-1$
- Composites of the form $m = 24k+23$ has at least $8$ divisors of $\phi(m)$ which do not divide $m-1$

$$
\cdots
$$

- Composites of the form $m = 48k+11$ has at least $14$ divisors of $\phi(m)$ which do not divide $m-1$

In fact each of the above arithmetic progressions is the smallest (lowest coefficient of $k$) for a given $n$ and there could be more than one arithmetic progression with the above property.

> **Claim**: For $n \ge 1$ there is an arithmetic
>   progression $m_k = ak + b $ such that if $m_k$ composite then there are 
>   at least $n$ divisors of $\phi(m_k)$ which do not divide $m_k-1$.

**Question**: Can we find a counter example i.e. is there an integer $n$ for which at we cannot find such an arithmetic progression?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying there are $4$ factors of $\phi(27)=18$ that don't divide $27=8\times3+3$?

Comment: Are the claims about $8k+3$ etc. just numerical observations or did you prove each of these? Also, you are interested in divisors of $m-1$, but write $m$ in the item list?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think it is meant that $3,6,9,18$ do not divide $27\color{red}{-1}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen:  thanks; that makes more sense

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The confusion is due to typing error. The explanation by Hagen correct, there are $4$ divisors of $\phi(27)$ which do not divide $27-1$.

Comment: It will be already extremely difficult to prove a minimum number of divisors with the desired property for a single arithmetic progression.